# The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview

I'm trying to build a pager to display images, sequentially. But I am getting this error.

```
The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! 
Expected adapter item count: 0, found: 1 Pager id:.
```

Please someone guide to fix it.

This is my code:

**MatChedUserProfile Activity**

```
public class MatChedUserProfile extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MatChedUserProfile";
    private static boolean mDebugLog = true;
    private static String mDebugTag = "MatChedUserProfile";
    private ExtendedGallery imageExtendedGallery;
    private LinearLayout image_count;
    private TextView usernametextivew, ueragetextviw, distancetextview,
            activetimetextview, abouttextview, abouttextviewvalues,
            viewMatchedProfiletextview, statusTextView;
    private RelativeLayout Aboutuseragelayout, likedislikebuttonlayout;
    private Button likeButton, dislikebutton;
    private ArrayList<GellaryData> imageList;

//private ImageAdapterForGellary mAdapterForGellary;
private ProgressDialog mDialog;
private int[] imageHeightandWIdth;
private ConnectionDetector cd;
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
private int count;
private TextView[] page_text;
private SharedPreferences preferences;

//new viewpager....
private ViewPager viewPager;
private MyViewPagerAdapter mAdapterForGellary;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.matcheduserprofile);
    //Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CrashLogger(getApplicationContext()));
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(this);
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    initLayoutResource();

    imageList = new ArrayList<GellaryData>();
    //listOfItems=new ArrayList<GellaryData>();

    mAdapterForGellary = new MyViewPagerAdapter(imageList);

    //imageExtendedGallery.setAdapter(mAdapterForGellary);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapterForGellary);


    Ultilities ultilities = new Ultilities();

    imageHeightandWIdth = ultilities
            .getImageHeightAndWidthForProfileGellary(this);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.getBoolean(Constant.isFromChatScreen)) {
            likedislikebuttonlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {

        }
    }


    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehaviors.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);


    try {
        likeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        dislikebutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            imageHeightandWIdth[1], imageHeightandWIdth[0]);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    layoutParams = ultilities.getRelativelayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);

    layoutParams = ultilities.getRelativelayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        getUserProfile();
        // getUserShareeInterest();
    } else {
        AlertDialogManager
                .internetConnetionErrorAlertDialog(MatChedUserProfile.this);
    }

    //myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(imageList);

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapterForGellary);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

/*  imageExtendedGallery
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int pos, long id) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        page_text[i]
                                .setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GRAY);
                    }
                    page_text[pos]
                            .setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.LTGRAY);

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });*/

}

//  page change listener
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            page_text[i]
                    .setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GRAY);
        }
        page_text[position]
                .setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.LTGRAY);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
};



private void initLayoutResource() {

    viewMatchedProfiletextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewMatchedProfiletextview);
    likeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.likeButton);
    dislikebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dislikebutton);
    //imageExtendedGallery = (ExtendedGallery) findViewById(R.id.imageExtendedGallery);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    image_count = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_count);
    usernametextivew = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernametextivew);
    ueragetextviw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ueragetextviw);
    distancetextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distancetextview);
    activetimetextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activetimetextview);
    statusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMatchedUserStatus);
    // userfriendgallery = (HorizontalListView)
    // findViewById(R.id.userfriendgallery);
    // userIntestedgallery = (HorizontalListView)
    // findViewById(R.id.userIntestedgallery);
    abouttextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abouttextview);
    Aboutuseragelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Aboutuseragelayout);
    Aboutuseragelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    likedislikebuttonlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.likedislikebuttonlayout);
    abouttextviewvalues = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abouttextviewvalues);


    Typeface HelveticaInseratLTStd_Roman = Typeface.createFromAsset(
            getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaInseratLTStd-Roman.otf");
    Typeface HelveticaLTStd_Light = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Light.otf");
    viewMatchedProfiletextview.setTypeface(HelveticaLTStd_Light);
    viewMatchedProfiletextview.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    viewMatchedProfiletextview.setTextSize(20);

    usernametextivew.setTypeface(HelveticaInseratLTStd_Roman);
    usernametextivew.setTextColor(Color.rgb(124, 124, 124));
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtst))
            .setTypeface(HelveticaInseratLTStd_Roman);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtst)).setTextColor(Color.rgb(124, 124,
            124));
    statusTextView.setTypeface(HelveticaInseratLTStd_Roman);
    statusTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(124, 124, 124));
    // usernametextivew.setTextSize(20);

    ueragetextviw.setTypeface(HelveticaLTStd_Light);
    ueragetextviw.setTextColor(Color.rgb(124, 124, 124));

    abouttextview.setTypeface(HelveticaInseratLTStd_Roman);
    abouttextview.setTextColor(Color.rgb(92, 92, 92));
    abouttextview.setTextSize(15);

    abouttextviewvalues.setTypeface(HelveticaInseratLTStd_Roman);
    abouttextviewvalues.setTextColor(Color.rgb(131, 131, 131));
    abouttextviewvalues.setTextSize(15);

    distancetextview.setTypeface(HelveticaInseratLTStd_Roman);
    distancetextview.setTextColor(Color.rgb(92, 92, 92));
    distancetextview.setTextSize(15);

    activetimetextview.setTypeface(HelveticaInseratLTStd_Roman);
    activetimetextview.setTextColor(Color.rgb(131, 131, 131));
    activetimetextview.setTextSize(15);
}

private void getUserProfile() {
    SessionManager mSessionManager = new SessionManager(this);

    String macheduserFacebookid = mSessionManager
            .getMatchedUserFacebookId();
    AppLog.Log(TAG, "Matched UserFacebook ID:" + macheduserFacebookid);
    // String userSessionToken = mSessionManager.getUserToken();
    String userDeviceId = Ultilities.getDeviceId(this);
    if (macheduserFacebookid != null && macheduserFacebookid.length() > 0) {
        // String[] params = { userSessionToken, userDeviceId,
        // macheduserFacebookid };
        String[] params = { macheduserFacebookid };
        new BackGroundTaskForUserProfile().execute(params);
    } else {
        ErrorMessageMandetoryFiledMissing(
                getResources().getString(R.string.alert), getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.retriedmessage));
    }
}

private class BackGroundTaskForUserProfile extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    Ultilities mUltilities = new Ultilities();
    private String getProfileResponse;
    private List<NameValuePair> userProfileNameValuePairList;
    private userProFileData mUserProFileData;
    private GellaryData mGellaryData;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            userProfileNameValuePairList = mUltilities
                    .getUserProfileParameter(params);
            getProfileResponse = mUltilities.makeHttpRequest(
                    Constant.getProfile_url, Constant.methodeName,
                    userProfileNameValuePairList);

            // logDebug("BackGroundTaskForUserProfile  getProfileResponse "+getProfileResponse);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            mUserProFileData = gson.fromJson(getProfileResponse,
                    userProFileData.class);

            String[] images = mUserProFileData.getImages();


            for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                mGellaryData = new GellaryData();

                mGellaryData.setImageUrl(images[i]);
                imageList.add(mGellaryData);

            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (mDialog != null) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    page_text = new TextView[imageList.size()];
                    count = imageList.size();
                    image_count.removeAllViews();
                    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {
                        page_text[i] = new TextView(MatChedUserProfile.this);
                        page_text[i].setText(".");
                        page_text[i].setTextSize(45);
                        page_text[i].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        page_text[i]
                                .setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GRAY);
                        image_count.addView(page_text[i]);

                    }

                    //Log.d("shanImage", Array.toString(mUserProFileData.getImages()));
                    mAdapterForGellary.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    if (mUserProFileData.getStatus() != null
                            && !mUserProFileData.getStatus().equals("")) {
                        statusTextView
                                .setText(mUserProFileData.getStatus());
                    } else {
                        statusTextView.setText("N/A");
                    }
                    ueragetextviw.setText("" + mUserProFileData.getAge());
                    usernametextivew.setText(""
                            + mUserProFileData.getFirstName());
                    viewMatchedProfiletextview.setText(""
                            + mUserProFileData.getFirstName());


                    SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(
                            MatChedUserProfile.this);
                    String DistanceUinit = null;
                    if (sessionManager.getDistaceUnit().equals("Km")) {
                        DistanceUinit = "Km.";
                    } else {
                        DistanceUinit = "Mi.";
                    }

                    distancetextview.setText("Less than "
                            + mUserProFileData.getDistance() + " "
                            + DistanceUinit + " away");
                    String gmtTime = mUserProFileData.getLastActive();
                    // gmtTime=gmtTime.replaceAll("-", " ");

                    String localTime = UltilitiesDate.getLocalTime(gmtTime);
                    Ultilities ultilities = new Ultilities();
                    // String
                    // curentTime=ultilities.getCurrentDateYYYYMMdd();
                    String dataString = UltilitiesDate
                            .datesString(localTime);
                    UltilitiesDate ultilitiesDate = new UltilitiesDate();
                    int days = ultilitiesDate.getDays();
                    int hours = ultilitiesDate.getHours();

                    activetimetextview.setText("active " + days + " -d  "
                            + hours + "- Hour ago");
                    if (mUserProFileData.getPersDesc() != null
                            && mUserProFileData.getPersDesc().length() > 0) {
                        Aboutuseragelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        abouttextview.setText("About  " + ""
                                + mUserProFileData.getFirstName());
                        abouttextviewvalues.setText(""
                                + mUserProFileData.getPersDesc());

                    } else {
                        Aboutuseragelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.Log(TAG,
                    "BackGroundTaskForUserProfile   doInBackground Exception"
                            + e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {

            if (mDialog != null) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.Log(TAG,
                    "BackGroundTaskForUserProfile   onPostExecute Exception  "
                            + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mDialog = mUltilities.GetProcessDialog(MatChedUserProfile.this);
        mDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();
    }

}
```

**ImageAdapterForGellary Adapter**

```
private class ImageAdapterForGellary extends PagerAdapter {
    Activity mActivity;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Ultilities mUltilities = new Ultilities();

    private int[] imageheightandWidth = mUltilities
            .getImageHeightAndWidthForGellary(MatChedUserProfile.this);

    public ImageAdapterForGellary(
            List<GellaryData> objects) {

        //mActivity = context;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public GellaryData getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleritem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            // holder.mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView
            // .findViewById(R.id.pbGalleryItemImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // holder.mProgressBar.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);

        Picasso.with(MatChedUserProfile.this) //
                .load(getItem(position).getImageUrl()) //
                .error(R.drawable.error) //
                .resize(imageHeightandWIdth[1], imageHeightandWIdth[0]) //
                .into(holder.imageview);

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        // ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    }
}
```

**MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter**

```
//  adapter
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    //private ArrayList<Integer> items;
    private List<GellaryData> items;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter(List<GellaryData> objects) {
        this.items = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleritem, container,false);

        ImageView galleimageview = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);


        Picasso.with(MatChedUserProfile.this) //
                .load(imageList.get(position).getImageUrl()) //
                .error(R.drawable.error) //
                .resize(imageHeightandWIdth[1], imageHeightandWIdth[0]) //
                .into(galleimageview);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(view);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == ((View)obj);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View)object;
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView(view);
    }
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    // FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, Constant.flurryKey);

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    // FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);

}
}
```

And this is my error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 0, found: 1 Pager id: com.crushmatic.pro:id/viewPager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.fresh.slidingmenu.MatChedUserProfile$MyViewPagerAdapter
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1000)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1927)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1006)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5652)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            mGellaryData = new GellaryData();

            mGellaryData.setImageUrl(images[i]);
            imageList.add(mGellaryData);

        }
```

this is what is causing the crash you can't add multiple objects to an array that is attached to an adapter inside a for loop

move this

```
 mAdapterForGellary = new MyViewPagerAdapter(imageList);

//imageExtendedGallery.setAdapter(mAdapterForGellary);
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapterForGellary);
```

to on post execute of the task

Comment: Still it is getting crashed

Comment: can you trace which line is causing the crash?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your pager adapter

```
 // Trying to add data dynamically
public void addData(@NonNull List<Object> data) {
    mData.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

after that in your main method

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext());
myViewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter); 
myViewPager.setScrollMode(UltraViewPager.ScrollMode.HORIZONTAL);
myViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new UltraDepthScaleTransformer());

// Runs after data loaded from server (in the future):
myAdapter.addData(myData)
```

i hope this helps.